# (Python Newb) Writing to file what is printed?

Tags: python, gdata

Thanks to the kindness on this website i've installed 2.7/setuptools/feedparser all without issue.. I've figured out feedparser and it works without issue.

I've been reading tutorials on how to write to file (text) via python, i've had moderate success doing this with text.. However when I try to write a list of data it goes all screwy on me and does nothing at all.

ORIGINAL:

```
import feedparser

result = feedparser.parse('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Ej4_G-E1cAM/comments')
for entry in result.entries:
print entry.author
```

MY ATTEMPT:

```
import feedparser

result = feedparser.parse('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Ej4_G-E1cAM/comments')
for entry in result.entries:
with open("write.txt", "w") as text_file:
text_file.write entry.author
```

I'm attempting to harvest comments for an upcoming giveaway on my YouTube channel.. If anyone is wondering what i'm using this seemingly useless data for.

Best Regards,
-Mitch Powell

Comment: Is this your actual code? `text_file.write entry.author` doesn't look like Python to me.

Comment: No, that didn't format properly.. I had another line in there.. i'll edit it, my apologies Kevin!. I'm extremley new to python, my only past "programming" experience was basic html and MSL for mIRC automation

Comment: What do you mean by "goes all screwy"?

Answer (score 0):

```
import feedparser
f = open('filename','w')
result = feedparser.parse('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Ej4_G-E1cAM/comments')
for entry in result.entries:
    f.write(entry.author)
```